# ExoPlayer2 how to loop a part / segment of a video

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer2.x

I have a video of 10 seconds. I want to loop a segment from 2 seconds to 6 seconds. Starting the player at the right time is easy:

```
player?.seekTo(2000)
```

I don't think there is a functionality available in the ExoPlayer2 library to define an end position. So I tried to add a delay co-routine. With the method `seekToPositionAndStartCounter`. This works in a separate project. But used in the actual project, `onPlayerStateChanged` gets triggered a lot of times all of a sudden.

```
var elapsedTime = 0L // just for testing

private fun showVideoWhenDoneLoading() {
    videoView?.player?.addListener(object : Player.EventListener {
        override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
            super.onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady, playbackState)
            if (playbackState == Player.STATE_READY) {
                if (playWhenReady) {
                    seekToPositionAndStartCounter()
                } else {
                    cancelCounter()
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

private fun seekToPositionAndStartCounter() {
    elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

    cancelCounter()
    job = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        Timber.d("starting Thread name = ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        player?.seekTo(startPosition)

        if (duration != 0L) {
            runBlocking {
                delay(duration)
            }
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                Timber.d("duration = $duration elapsedTime = ${System.currentTimeMillis()-elapsedTime} Thread name = ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                seekToPositionAndStartCounter()
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun cancelCounter() {
    job?.cancel()
    job = null
}
```

Comment: If you just want to loop the segment between 2s and 6s, then maybe having a combination of ClippingMediaSource and LoopingMediaSource to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't try this then think about this.

`getCurrentPosition` of player and if player reach end position which you want then run `player.seekto(2)` it loops the video in specific segment of video.